# check validity for flag column's in multiple rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe:

```
a      id   flag1    flag2
abc    1     1          0
123    1     0          1
xyz    2     1          0
111    2     0          1
qwe    3     1          0
qwe    3     1          0
mmm    4     1          0
222    4     0          1
```

i want to find the `id` number where both flag1 and flag2 are `1`.

for eg.
 for id 1, in the first row, flag1 = 1 and flag2 = 0, and second row, flag1 = 0 and flag2 = 1.

my final output should look like this

```
a    id    flag1   flag2
abc    1     1          0
123    1     0          1
xyz    2     1          0
111    2     0          1
mmm    4     1          0
222    4     0          1
```

or only id column would also work `[1,2,4]` in a list

since for id = 3, flag1 was 1 in both the rows with id = 3 and flag 2 was 0, so i have to neglect it.

i was trying to write a func, but failed.

```
def checkValidTransactionRow(frame):
df['id'][(df['flag1']==1) & (df['flag2']==1) ].unique()
```

Comment: @jezrael can you take a look?

Comment: In my opinion both solution are nice, but seems maxu solution is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
In [23]: ids = df.groupby('id')['flag1','flag2'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).any()).all(1)

In [24]: ids
Out[24]:
id
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

In [25]: ids.index[ids]
Out[25]: Int64Index([1, 2, 4], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

Explanation:

```
In [26]: df.groupby('id')['flag1','flag2'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).any())
Out[26]:
   flag1  flag2
id
1   True   True
2   True   True
3   True  False
4   True   True
```

`x.eq(1).any()` is the same as `(x == 1).any()` - i.e. return `True` if at least one value in `x` series equals to `1`, otherwise return `False`

**UPDATE:**

```
In [34]: ids.index[ids].values
Out[34]: array([1, 2, 4], dtype=int64)

In [35]: ids.index[ids].values.tolist()
Out[35]: [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: i am getting `type(ids)` as series, can i get ids where it is only true?
also what does `lambda x: x.eq(1).any()` mean?

Comment: If possible can you explain `lambda x: x.eq(1).any()` mean in words?
i am getting right answer but didnt understand the code

Comment: when i am running this code it is working fine, but when i am using this part of my code in a big python program, it is giving me error
`exceptions.keyerror`

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a better way of achieving this but you can try:

```
df['count_max1'] = df.groupby(['id'])['flag1'].transform(max)
df['count_max2'] = df.groupby(['id'])['flag2'].transform(max)
# Select rows 
df[(df['count_max1'] ==1 & (df['count_max2'] == 1)]
```

What transform matrix does is:

```
a      id   flag1    flag2    count_max1   count_max2
abc    1     1          0         1            1
123    1     0          1         1            1
xyz    2     1          0         1            1
111    2     0          1         1            1
qwe    3     1          0         1            0
qwe    3     1          0         1            0
mmm    4     1          0         1            1
222    4     0          1         1            1
```

When you select the rows the final output will be:

```
a    id    flag1   flag2    count_max1  count_max2
abc    1     1          0       1            1
123    1     0          1       1            1
xyz    2     1          0       1            1
111    2     0          1       1            1
mmm    4     1          0       1            1
222    4     0          1       1            1
```

you can drop the rows count_max1 and count_max2 later on

Comment: what does transform(max) does?

Comment: yes, but i didn't understand why for row `qwe` count_max2 is 0

Comment: because maximum value of flag2 is 0 for qwe

Comment: @jezrael any better solution than this?