# How do changed the dtypes of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and I created a list with all the items I wanted to convert to numbers:

```
lst = [var1, var3, var5]
```

when I try to change the items to numeric:

```
df= df[[lst]].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

I get an error:

```
HashError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I change the dtypes from a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[lst] = df[lst].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

Comment: @jezrael is GOD of pandas! :)

Comment: @SRingne - I think no, devs are much better. But they make new version of pandas, so no time for SO ;)

Comment: I agree with both of you :-)

Comment: @jezrael please see this, any better solution for python 2.7 `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449478/check-validity-for-flag-columns-in-multiple-rows-pandas/43450004?noredirect=1#comment73955661_43450004`

Comment: @S Ringne hmmm, obviously it is hard know what is better, but timings can helps. But if in solution is groupby, it is a bit complicated, because need custom sample. But Maxu is really smart and this sample can create. So if in future need similar decision, what is better ask for timings in larger df from answerers. Good luck!